# How to update the code below in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: xcode

I am rookie to Xcode and I am having issue converting the code below in the new Xcode 6.0.1. Appreciate your help guys, thank you very much.

NSInteger h2 = [text sizeWithFont:_textView.font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;

Comment: What's the error, for a start?

Answer (score 0):

its not a issue of Xcode 6.0.1 its a depecreted method sizeWithFont in ios7.the replacement of this method is as follows

```
//Following is macro for checking ios6 or 7 OS.
    #define isIOS6 floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 
    #define isIOS7 floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1

    //Use following which will work both for ios7 and for ios6 version too

        if (isIOS6) {
                //version <= 6.0

                return [text sizeWithFont:_textView.font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
            }
            else if (isIOS7) {
                //version for > 6.0

                //Return the calculated height of the Label
                return [_textView boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(_textView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                   attributes:@{
                                                                NSFontAttributeName : _textView.font
                                                                }
                                                      context:nil].size.height;

            }
```

Comment: I'm having 2 errors with it. 1) Void method 'adjustTextInputHeightForText:animated:' should not return a value 2) No visible @interface for 'UITextView' declares the selector 'boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:'